# Which updates to install to reach the latest version of Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

There are a handful of patches for Delphi 2007 in my Registered Users downloads page. (This page is quite unwieldy if you have more than a few registered versions.)  I no longer recall what is the proper combination to get the latest version of Delphi 2007 installed.

Is there an ISO available with all the patches, or what is the recommended way to get the latest fully patched Delphi 2007?  The only ISO appears to be **CodeGear RAD Studio 2007 ISO (Dec 2007)** and I assume that isn't the latest fully patched version due to the Dec 2007 tag.

It seems the proper combination is:

- R2 install from the web (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26910)
- April 08 Hotfix (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/25495)
- June 08 Linker Hotfix (this is for C++ Builder only) (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/25694)
- May/June 08 Help Update 4 (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/25688)
- Debugger fix for Windows 7 (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27521)

Comment: Not necessarily against anything, but is this an appropriate question for StackOverflow?

Comment: @Jerry: It's perfectly fine. This site is for programming and programmers tools questions, and Delphi 2007 is a programmers tool the last time I checked. (The IDE used for programming is an on-topic subject here, unless the question is for a shopping-list of possible IDEs to use for some purpose.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the only things you need are:

- R2, which is a cumulative update, and contains all of the updates prior to it.
- Help Update 4
- the Win7 debugger patch

Here's the relevant portion of the `Help->About` dialog from my copy of Delphi 2007:

[image: Portion of Delphi 2007 Help About Dialog]

Comment: I think you are correct... will wait a little bit to see if others confirm.  Thanks!

Comment: i wonder if this debugger patch applciable to 2006 as well. We'd liek to try remote debugging on Win7x64 box from XP/BDS2006 machine. But as soon as we try to attach to remote process (or run it, which includes attaching) the IDE freezes. BTW when killing IDE process, debug server dies too. And win7 was throwing "incompatible" messages against CLR 1.1 and .Net SDK 1.1 required by remote debugger"

Comment: @Arioch'The: I don't think it works on 2K6; I think support for that version of Delphi was gone by the time Win7 was released. I didn't know anyone was still using D2K6 any more; it was pretty buggy.

Comment: Truly it is. But 2k7 was told to be binary compatible - unprecedented for Delphi - thus i thought maybe it is known if debuggers are compatible as well.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Hmmm... I really don't know, but it seems like it might be. I'd do some careful backups and give it a try; if you're *very careful*, it shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: Thanks... Alas we only have 2006 licensed, if back then they knew in advance to postpone the upgrade :-)

Comment: The hotfixes won't show up in the About box, so I think you're missing the April/June hotfixes - I'm asking for clarification from Embarcadero today as I'm re-installing D2007 again.